# Vue3 - Argument of type '*' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<*>'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Project: Vue3 Plugin
Vue 3: ^3.1.0
Vite: ^4.3.8

I'm currently learning typescript and trying to switch a project over to vue 3. I'm having an issue with my IDE (VScode) showing an error when it shouldn't be.

The error comes with initialising a class that extends my base field class.

```
Argument of type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<RadioField>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'label' does not exist in type 'Partial<RadioField>'.
```

I understand the error (or at least what the message ss saying), but I have other classes extended from the base class, and they do not throw this error when initialising.

The code that is throwing this error looks like this:

```
const radio: RadioField = new RadioField({
    label: 'test',
    value: 'test',
})
```

Code that works fine:

```
const switch: SwitchField = new SwitchField({
    label: 'Select / Deselect All'
})
```

The base class:

```
export class BaseField implements HasField {
    public label: string = '';
    public value: any;
  
    constructor(init?: Partial<BaseField>) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
    }
  
}
```

Radio Field class that throws errors on initialisation:

```
import { BaseField } from 'classes/fields/BaseField';

export class RadioField extends BaseField {
  
  public inline: boolean = false;

  constructor(init?: Partial<RadioField>) {
    super(init)
    Object.assign(this, init);

  }
}
```

Switch class that initialises fine.

```
import { BaseField } from 'classes/fields/BaseField';
export class SwitchField extends BaseField {
  public inset: boolean = false;

  constructor(init?: Partial<SwitchField>) {
    super(init)
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

}
```

I've simplified the classes so the code is easier to read.

I believe this is just an IDE issue (although I could be wrong?), but I am unsure why this class throws an error when all others work fine (following the same structure).

Some things I noticed:

1. It only seems to throw errors on the parent class variables (in this example, label)
2. If I removed the parent variables from initialising the child class, the error would go away.
3. The project builds fine and runs dev with no errors (vite). In fact, it actually initialises properly when the component loads, the values are correct (this is what led me to believe it was just a IDE problem).

Additional Info:
package.json scripts:

```
 "dev": "vite",
 "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
 "build:types": "vue-tsc --project tsconfig.build-types.json --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist/types "
```

Comment: can you reproduce on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ?

Comment: @Dimava unfortunately not, as expected it runs fine. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but if I put the files in the same folder the error goes away.